# JavaFX 8 : Where is TextField key/mouse handling done?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I'm creating a TextField-subclass to handle time input. I want to disable selecting the text with the mouse or Maj-Left, Maj-Right, Ctrl+A, etc...

Where can I find the place in the JavaFX source code which handles all this stuff ? I did not find anything in the TextField/TextInput control. I need to see how it's done to figure out the best way to disable it.

Thank you,

Thibaut

Comment: May i know the purpose? If its to disable copying, you can just override the `copy()` method.

Comment: I want to write a TimePicker widget, where input is a text in of the form "HH:MM:SS". I want the user to be able to click on HH or MM or SS, select (programatically) HH or MM or SS accordingly and let him type some value or use Up/Down to change the value. I want to allow selection to done by the code only, not by the user.

Comment: They are defined in (the non-public API class) [`com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/TextFieldBehavior.java)

Comment: Thanks @James_D, if you make a real answer I'll validate it :-)